# Uncontrolled Tooltip from reactstrap crashes if innerHTML is a bit longer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following `UncontrolledTooltip` from [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/):

```
<UncontrolledTooltip trigger="hover"
                     placement="right-start"
                     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
                        props.ability.name + '<br /><br />' +
                        props.ability.description +
                        props.ability.rank
                     }}
                     target={'UncontrolledTooltip' + props.ability.id}>
</UncontrolledTooltip>
```

Which basically creates a hover tooltip for each ability on my website and displays, e.g. the ability name, rank, description and so on.

`.description` is in my case a HTML string which is why I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

This solution works fine on PC but on phone, it freezes the page completely as soon as you hover over the ability.
Chrome phone inspection tool shows over 100% CPU usage for that tab. I even tried to insert clean strings instead of the ability data into the tooltip but the results are the same. 
Does someone know what is causing this and what could be a possible solution?

Comment: "This solution works fine on PC.... Chrome phone inspection tool shows over 100% CPU usage" That doesn't sound like works fine to me

Comment: @Patte Maybe i phrased it wrong but what I meant is that the page works fine on PC but if you browse it via a physical phone or use the built in phone view via Chome it freezes, hence why I am asking this question.

Comment: Have you tried to use the normal `Tooltip` instead of the `UncontrolledTooltip`, to see if you got the same error?

Answer (score 1):

It's the correct behavior, the `preventOverflow` modifier uses by default, as `boundariesElement`, the `scrollParent`, you can change it to viewport or window or anything else supported.

So, I resolved the issue by adding the modifiers prop to the UncontrolledTooltip:

```
<UncontrolledTooltip **modifiers={{preventOverflow: {boundariesElement: 'window'}}} autohide={false}** delay={{ show: 200, hide: 5 }} placement='left' target={...}> ... </UncontrolledTooltip>
```